# Get next value of big serial and insert

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I have the following table, In the present table we have data inserted manually like shown below but now I want to insert latest `cola` values into table.

```
create table tbTest
(
    cola bigserial not null primary key,
    colb varchar(10)
);

insert into tbTest(cola,colb) values(1,'A');
insert into tbTest(cola,colb) values(2,'B');
insert into tbTest(cola,colb) values(3,'C');
insert into tbTest(cola,colb) values(4,'D');
insert into tbTest(cola,colb) values(5,'E');
insert into tbTest(cola,colb) values(6,'F');
```

Now I want insert only column `colb` values and let serial column calculate next value by self:

Try 1:

```
insert into tbTest(colb) values('G')
```

Error: `SQL Error [23505]: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tbtest_pkey" Detail: Key (cola)=(1) already exists.`

Try 2:

```
insert into tbTest(cola,colb) values(nextval('tbtest_cola_seq'),'G')
```

Error: `SQL Error [23505]: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tbtest_pkey" Detail: Key (cola)=(2) already exists.`

Try 3:

```
insert into tbTest(cola,colb) values(currval('tbtest_cola_seq')+1,'G');
```

Error: `SQL Error [23505]: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tbtest_pkey" Detail: Key (cola)=(3) already exists.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to adjust the sequence to start at a value greater than the maximum existing value.

First

```
SELECT max(cola) FROM tbtest;
```

to get the maximum.

Then reset the sequence:

```
SELECT setval('tbtest_cola_seq', 42);
```

where 42 is bigger than the value returned by the first query.